# Bouncycastle HTTPS, ignoring certificate validation issues

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bouncycastle

I am developing a BlackBerry (OS 5) application that needs to make a HTTPS call to a server. The server has a self-signed certificate. I cannot ignore or suppress validation errors on the BlackBerry side using only the J2ME classes available so I want to use Bouncycastle's light TLS library to achieve this.

My code:

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("https://<myserversite>");
TlsProtocolHandler tlsHandler = new TlsProtocolHandler(sc.openInputStream(),         
sc.openOutputStream());
CertificateVerifyer cv = new AlwaysValidVerifyer();
tlsHandler.connect(cv);
DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(tlsHandler.getOutputStream());
InputStream inputStream = tlsHandler.getInputStream();
```

I am using Bouncycastle lightweight API ver 1.46, with Java 1.6

I am experiencing a few issues:

1. I get an exception thrown when I attempt to connect: "Internal TLS error, this could be an attack". I've debugged and it's thrown when Bouncycastle does a version check via TlsUtils.checkVersion(InputStream is, TlsProtocolHandler handler). I've tried searching for the cause for this but cannot determine what is happening. I also get this same exception when attempting to connect to another (trusted) HTTPS-enabled site.
2. AlwaysValidVerifyer has been deprecated. The javadoc states that " Perform certificate verification in TlsAuthentication implementation" but I cannot find any samples of how to do this - can anyone help with a sample?
3. I've tried to search for J2ME compatible HTTPS libraries to use but cannot find any other than Bouncycastle - can anyone suggest another library?

Any help is much appreciated

Will

Comment: Hi @Will777 did you succeed with this? i am now facing the same issue. Can you take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318651/connect-j2me-application-to-https-with-self-signed-certificate

Comment: Sorry, shortly after posting this question, we abandoned Blackberry development as the Blackberry footprint in my country dropped significantly

Comment: Hi again @WILL777 i succeed to run my j2me app with self-signed certificate, if you interest just add a comment.

Comment: Manee - post your solution so others with the same problem can access it

Comment: I already solve it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318651/connect-j2me-application-to-https-with-self-signed-certificate.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("https://<myserversite>");
```

To

```
SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://<myserversite>:443");
```

Comment: user1647750: What does this post have to do with the question? My question is regarding accepting self-signed certificates on the BlackBerry platform.

Comment: It will get rid of your 1st issue. Are you doing SSL Certification pinning related work?

Comment: The first issue I am referring to is the certificate validation issue due to the CA being self-signed and not being in the device trust store. How will your suggestion address that? With regards to pinning - I am self-signing certificates with my own, development-use CA - that is all