# connect J2ME application to https with self-signed certificate

Tags: java, tomcat, java-me, midp

I know this question was asked before. but i really don't know how to do this.

I created a j2me app and a webservice in a tomcat server, it works perfect on HTTP, **Now** i need to connect to HTTPS/TLS.

**To do that i followed this steps:**

1. using KeyTool i generate a .keystore file in the server–side.
2. i run HTTPS correctly in tomcat (in web browser).
3. i took the .keystore and i import it to my WTK keys stores. by using Mekeytool.

When i try to connect to my https://server-ip/webservice, using this snippet of code:

```
public class HttpsMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, Runnable {
private Display mDisplay;
private Form mForm;

public void startApp() {
    mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);

    if (mForm == null) {
        mForm = new Form("HttpsMIDlet");

        mForm.addCommand(new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0));
        mForm.addCommand(new Command("Send", Command.SCREEN, 0));
        mForm.setCommandListener(this);
    }

    mDisplay.setCurrent(mForm);
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable s) {
    if (c.getCommandType() == Command.EXIT)
        notifyDestroyed();
    else {
        Form waitForm = new Form("Connecting...");
        mDisplay.setCurrent(waitForm);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}

public void run() {
    String url = "https://server-ip/webserive";

    try {
        // Query the server and retrieve the response.
        HttpsConnection hc = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open(url);

        SecurityInfo si = hc.getSecurityInfo();
        Certificate c = si.getServerCertificate();
        String subject = c.getSubject();
        System.out.println();

        String s = "Server certificate subject: \n" + subject;
        Alert a = new Alert("Result", s, null, null);
        a.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
        mDisplay.setCurrent(a, mForm);

        hc.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Alert a = new Alert("Exception", ioe.toString(), null, null);
        System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        a.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
        mDisplay.setCurrent(a, mForm);
    }
}
```

**It throws this Exception:**

```
java.io.IOException: Bad record type (21) or version (3.3)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Record.rdRec(+284)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Record.rdRec(+5)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.getNextMsg(+17)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.rcvSrvrHello(+5)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.Handshake.doHandShake(+29)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.SSLStreamConnection.<init>(+173)
at com.sun.midp.ssl.SSLStreamConnection.<init>(+12)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.https.Protocol.connect(+214)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(+57)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(+12)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(+38)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(+6)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.openInputStream(+9)
```

Some help please. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By doing search for more than 15 days, this **Exception** issue solved by installing an old versions for both tomcat and JDK.

This may be occurred in differentiation of the WTK and tomcat/JDK versions, which handle the HTTPS/SSL connection.

1. `for tomcat 1.5`
2. `for java version JKD 1.5_0_u7`

I hope this may help others.